# Java 17, Maven 3.9.3 Error on running project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I use netbeans and I have Java 17 installed on my MacBook Pro M1 chip os Ventura. I installed maven with:

```
brew install maven
```

I ran mvn --version and I get (I am not sure if java version 20.0.1 counts there):

```
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.3/libexec
Java version: 20.0.1, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/20
```

If I check :

```
Java --version
```

I get :

```
java 17 2021-09-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS-2724)
```

I set HOME PATH to where brew installed maven:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

I see at the top this cause I set the path like this:

```
export
PATH="$PATH:/Users/MyName/flu/flutter/bin:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9$
```

I ran to redo all :

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

I am creating a new web application with maven project on netbeans. I run the project and I get this error:

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.9.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:3.9.3 (absent): org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:3.9.3 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I got this pom.xml file like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>w1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>w1-1.0-SNAPSHOT</name>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <jakartaee>10.0.0</jakartaee>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I tried to add all details here. What do you think it's causing this error ?

I even tried in my project folder:

```
mvn clean install
```

Comment: I see that dependency in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin (but not in version 3.9.3 ) but i don't see it at all in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 - maybe try with 3.6.0 ?

Comment: All the plugin versions you have defined are wrong..please check here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: yes, I kept modifying them after reading on stack overflow.

Comment: I switch to 3.6.0 version on pom.xml then I I ran ```mvn clean install``` and I got same error but instead of maven 3.9.3 I got 3.6.0 :(( What to do ?

Answer (score -1):

OMG. It finally worked. If somebody get this error in the future this is how pom.xml should look.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>w1</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>w1-1.0-SNAPSHOT</name>
  
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <jakartaee>10.0.0</jakartaee>
  </properties>
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>${jakartaee}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
          <compilerArguments>
            <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
          </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
              <silent>true</silent>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
                  <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Now I can go and eat in peace and happiness.

Comment: First the maven-compiler-plugin version is old... Use version 3.11.0. If you have defined properties like `<maven.compiler.source>..</maven.compiler.source>` you can remove the explicit configuration entries for them apart from that for JDK9+ you should use `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>` instead. Also `endorseddirs ` is not supported anymore since JDK11 (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html#GUID-2C896CA8-927C-4381-A737-B1D81D964B7B) and the jakarataee-api should defined as `<scope>provided</scope>` because it's provided.

Comment: For the maven-war-plugin the configuration `<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>` is already set to `false` by default since version 3.1.0...

Comment: While it's good that you resolved this issue yourself, could you update your answer to explain precisely what edits you needed to make to pom.xml to get things working? Apart from any specific changes you made, you have also modified the file's indentation, and this may make it tricky for readers to determine exactly what has changed. As it stands your answer is not very helpful.